# Oracle duplicate row detection

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the ideal way to display duplicate rows in Oracle? The trick here is that I am looking for all rows no just the multiples (duplicates). So for example on the below data set:

```
RSN fname   lname   emailaddress
1   John    Smith   j.smith@system.com
2   John    Smith   j.smith@system.com
3   John    Smith   j.smith@system.com
4   Kevin   Walker  k.walker@system.com
5   James   Kirk    j.kirk@system.com
6   James   Kirk    j.kirk@system.com
7   Kevin   James   k.james@system.com
8   Mike    Jones   m.jones@system.com
```

I would want the following returned:

```
1   John    Smith   j.smith@system.com
2   John    Smith   j.smith@system.com
3   John    Smith   j.smith@system.com
5   James   Kirk    j.kirk@system.com
6   James   Kirk    j.kirk@system.com
```

Any help?

Comment: here, let me [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+duplicate+rows) for you

Comment: I searched extensively, however, the results I found returned only the duplicates, that is the rows that are the second or higher instance of a given criteria. But thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT RSN, fname, lname, emailaddress
  FROM whatever_your_table_is_named t1
 WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM whatever_your_table_is_named t2
          WHERE t2.fname = t1.fname
            AND t2.lname = t1.lname
            AND t2.emailaddress = t1.emailaddress
            AND ROWNUM < 3
       ) > 1
;
```

Here's another:

```
SELECT t1.RSN, t1.fname, t1.lname, t1.emailaddress
  FROM whatever_your_table_is_named t1
  JOIN ( SELECT fname, lname, emailaddress
           FROM whatever_your_table_is_named
          GROUP
             BY fname, lname, emailaddress
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) t2
    ON t1.fname = t2.fname
   AND t1.lname = t2.lname
   AND t1.emailaddress = t2.emailaddress
;
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested either of these.)

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea how optimal it is, since obviously my Oracle skills aren't great, but it definitely works. Thanks ruakh!

Comment: That count(1) is ugly. It's non-standard and no better than count(*). Rumours of its superiority performance-wise are just myths.

Comment: Well any improvements are very welcome. I'll be running this against over a million records.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I'm aware that there's no performance advantage of `COUNT(1)` over `COUNT(*)` -- nor disadvantage, they're simply equivalent -- but I often use `COUNT` to count non-null values, so I find `COUNT(1)` (meaning "count the records where `1` is non-null") to be more logical than `COUNT(*)` (meaning "OMG magical syntax that costs an extra keystroke and looks like it should have something to do with other uses of `*` even though it doesn't"). When you say it's "ugly" and "non-standard", what do you mean by that?

Comment: count(\*) means "count the records" according to the ANSI SQL standard (and the documentation), so by definition anything else -- count(1), count(0), count('X') -- is non-standard. As I say, there's a myth that count(1) is faster than count(\*), so every time a person who believes in the myth sees it, it reinforces their false belief. When a person who has never heard of the myth sees it, it can lead to an "investigation" that converts them to a false belief. I think it should be discouraged, having as it does these disadvantages and no advantages.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: I'm sorry, but I think you don't know what you're talking about. See http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/sql/0596004818/4dot2dot-ansi-sql-aggregate-functions/id3752538.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: My point is that `COUNT(1)` (or `COUNT(0)` or `COUNT('X')`) is defined by the standard, making them, by definition, standard, which is, by definition, the exact opposite of non-standard. ;-)

Comment: The book to which you link does not mention them. In fact, it defines "COUNT(\*)" as "Counts all the rows in the target table whether or not they include NULLs". Any reasonable person using that book to understand how to simply count rows would conclude that count(\*) was the appropriate syntax.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Sure it does. You do realize that `1`, `0`, and `'X'` are expressions? (Or is the problem just that you misunderstand the term "non-standard"?)

Comment: Heh heh heh, I understand your internet sophistry -- that count(1) returns the same result as count(*). It compiles, runs, returns the right number, and therefore "meets the SQL syntax standard". Your logic is also good for defending the use of sum(1) or count(-1), so well done for that. count(1), sum(1), count(-100) ... none of them are the standard syntax for simply counting rows in a table, which is count(\*). I applaud your ingenuity, though.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: Yes, those are all perfectly standard, and they all count the number of rows. I think you're trying to abuse the standard here; obviously some constructions are more reasonable than others, but unreasonable ones are not automatically nonstandard. Just because there exists special syntax to do something, that doesn't mean it's nonstandard to do the same thing without using that syntax. This isn't sophistry, it's common sense. If you can't or won't understand that, then you should do yourself a favor and never read a standard again, because they will do you more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

this subquery will get the duplicates form the table.

```
    select *
    from (some table)
    where rsn IN (select rsn
                  from (some table) 
                   where fname IN 
                   (select fname
                    from (select fname, count(fname) as dup 
           from (some table)) where dup > 1)
```